# Perl Time::Piece use current date if not in format

Tags: perl, datetime

Consider this code:

```
use Time::Piece;
  
my $format="%I:%M %p";
my $from="9 am";

my $d_from = Time::Piece->strptime($from, $format);
print ($d_from);
```

This prints:

```
Thu Jan  1 09:00:00 1970
```

Let's assume I cannot change `$format` or `$from` . The format may or may not have d/m/y values -> how do I make sure the converted object uses current date/time values for the missing components?

My use-case is this: I am writing a rules engine where a user specifies an arbitrary date/time format and I need to match rules and execute if current date/time falls in that date/time. Since the user controls `$format` and `$from` I don't know if `$format` will contain a day/date.
It may just contain a time (example `$from="9 am"` means "9 am every day" if a date is not provided. When converting to a `Time::Piece` object I want to make sure missing fields are replaced with current date/time not start of epoch time.

Comment: It seems like it uses year = 1970 if you do not supply one, similarly for month it uses January if you do not supply a month and so on.. So an adhoc approach would be to check if year is equal to 1970 and if so replace with the current year, but this will fail if the user actually supplied 1970 for the year. On the other hand, the brute force approach is to check the format for any missing information that will cause `Time::Piece` to fill in a default value.

Comment: Correct, I thought of that approach and realized its not as clean for the same reason you mentioned - what if they actually wanted 1970. Practically however, in my case, expecting someone to put 1970 on purpose will likely not happen, in which case this may be the best fallback.

Answer (score 3):

Times and date/times are separate things, parse and treat them separately.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use v5.10;
 
my $from=shift;

# Put all your various date/time formats here.
my @DATE_TIME_FORMATS = (
    "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
);

# And all your various time formats here.
my @TIME_FORMATS = (
    "%I:%M %p"
);

# One function to try parsing a set of formats, first to match wins.
sub try_strptime {
    my($from, $formats) = @_;
    
    for my $format (@$formats) {
        my $time = eval { Time::Piece->strptime($from, $format) };
        return $time if $time;
    }
    
    return;
}

if( my $dt = try_strptime($from, \@DATE_TIME_FORMATS) ) {
    say "At $dt";
}
elsif( my $time = try_strptime($from, \@TIME_FORMATS) ) {
    say $time->time . " each day";
}
else {
    say "Can't recognize '$from'";
}
```

```
$ perl test.pl '10:23 pm'
22:23:00 each day

$ perl test.pl '05/10/2020 10:23 pm'
At Sun May 10 22:23:00 2020
```

Comment: Thank you. The additional issue here is I don't control the date/time format the user provides, so I cannot pass their dates through a "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" static format. For example, they might have chosen "%Y-%m-%d/ %H:%M"

Comment: @user1361529 Then you would try both formats in `try_datetime`. I'll edit.

Comment: I might not have explained properly. The format can be anything - I don't control it. The end-user defines any random time/date format. My task is to fill in current time/date values where things are missing. So I guess what I really was looking for was a way for Time::Piece not to take epoch time/date when elements are missing, but use current time/date.

Comment: @user1361529 If you don't know the format(s), you cannot parse them. You have to give `strptime` something, clearly you have made some educated guesses. Just separate those guesses into date/time formats vs time-only formats.

Comment: strptime will be given a specific format, as in the question above. The ask, specifically, is when we do `my $d_from = Time::Piece->strptime(""%I:%M %p", ""%I:%M %p");` it is intelligently parsing and seems to be filling in missing date/year with epoch start date (Jan 1 1970). If instead, I could get it to fill in current date instead, the problem is solved. Hope I was able to explain. The problem isn't that I don't know the format. The problem is if the date is not provided in the format and input (the format could be as varied as the user wants), it should be filled in with current date

Comment: @user1361529 Time::Piece is very simple and afaik is not able to be customized as you ask. My answer gives you the result you want: differentiating between date/times and just times. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern. Respectfully, my ask was not really addressed by the answer. Even if I separated time and date, I cannot guess what date format the person used. Example, if that person specified just "%Y" as date, Time::Piece would convert it to "Jan 1 2020" while I want "Sep 13 2020" (current day/month vs epoch start). I do understand however that Time::Piece doesn't allow me to do what I want and my best best is to actually do what Hakon suggested above.

Comment: @user1361529 Sure you can. Same as you'd parse date/times separate from times, you'd parse only years separately. `elsif( my $time = try_strptime($from, \@YEAR_FORMATS) ) { ... }`.

Comment: The problem is I can’t keep adding formats like this. The combinations are almost infinite. The key here is the user wi specify the time and date format. Not me. At the time of parsing the format is available but because I won’t know what it is I can’t pre add it to the arrays in your code.

Comment: @user1361529 I'd recommend you add what formats you can to get the best chance of a valid date, then use Håkon's technique as a fallback. Or use something like Time::ParseDate.